# Data from Cloudera cluster(which was mostly in hive tables) missing after a cluster restart

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I recently restarted a Cloudera cluster as i was having some problems with hue service. After the restart i can see the databases and tables in hive but once i run a statement to see the data, i get no rows. I have checked /user/hive directory in HDFS and see no warehouse directory. I feel like this is the case where the name node is not connecting to my data nodes but i am not sure about it. (The cluster is of 5 nodes).

I have tried to look through the logs and i did not find anything. There was one single CSV file in HDFS and i can see that it exists but the whole of /hive/warehouse directory is missing.

Thanks.

Comment: This might interest you https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/Does-hard-restart-of-agent-delete-data/m-p/49171

Comment: Wow! thanks for the link. Thats very interesting.